# Cheapest way to import over 10m entities to app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there a cheap way to import bulk data into app engine without paying for the datastore write operations?

I estimate that loading my 10m+ entities would cost 100+ dollars to get my data into app engine is there any other way? It seems like (accounting for indexs) each entity is taking 10 write operations can I cut it down to 1 write operation somehow?

Thanks

Comment: I would've thought it didn't result in any billing since "API usage with app engine is free" so I didn't know this operation would result in billing. +1 for letting me know. About GAE they said you don't pay for API usage ie I don't think using mapreduce results in billing even though it makes many reads/writes. I could be mistaken here since I don't have complete knowledge about app engine pricing.

Comment: Nick thanks for your comment, I'm not using map reduce to do my import. My understanding was map reduce can only iterate over existing entities. What I am doing is I have uploaded all the data to import into the task queue, and a servlet is processing the tasks dumping the data in the task into the database. While not being the most efficient way, it is the easiest for my case. From what I've read the remote_api basically does the same thing and I can't find any pricing information about the remote_api. If anyone knows if remote_api or map reduce is cheaper please let me know! Thanks

Comment: Also, this may help: I have no indexes defined for my app, and none show up when I click on view indexes, but so far I have 86,171 put operations, and 1,333,374 index write operations. The problem is definitely indexes, but I have none so I'm not sure what its doing

Comment: Mapreduce can iterate over anything, not just datastore entities. I don't know where @NickRosencrantz got "API usage with App Engine is free" from, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine maintains built-in indexes for each indexed property (i.e. those that don't have indexed=False as a parameter when defining the property).  See http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/index_building.html for more details.

If there are properties that won't appear in any of your queries, specify indexed=False as you are defining the property.  This will save you the cost of the index write operations associated with such properties that you don't need to be automatically indexed.

Comment: Ahhh I had lists that didn't need to be indexed, they must be implicitly indexed and wasting a bunch of money. Thanks so much!

Comment: Also, if you have composite indexes, upload them _after_ doing the bulkload, and you won't be charged for those indexes.